# Creating more than one label in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

*I have clarified the original question, so some of the original answers (prior to March 17 2017) will not be relevant to what I was trying to ask...*

How does one add a descriptor to each line of a stacked label?

As in the following extract:

[image]

I wish to add the "Thinning", "Species" and "Planting Year" text, along with the lines pointing to each of the stacked label levels (i.e. everything to the right of the green block).

Comment: What you are describing is known as stacked labels.

Comment: I've only now managed to get back to my desk to have a look at what has been suggested. What I'm looking to do is add a desciptor for the stacked labels (i.e. how do you add the lines and what is to the right of the lines in the picture above)

Comment: I think you should edit your question to make what you are asking much clearer.

Comment: Yeah, about that... Someone in their infinite wisdom edited both my question and title. My comment earlier today should make it sufficiently clear once again.

Comment: Comments do not form part of your question - they may or may not be read by potential answerers.

Answer (score 4):

Open the layer's Properties, select the Label tab and click the Label Expression. Build your expression by joining the fields you want to superpose with

`& vbcrlf &`

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However it is how to add a description of what each row of the stacked labels means, rather than how to create stacked labels, that I'm looking to do. See my reply to PolyGeo above.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a way to do exactly what you're wanting (except maybe making annotation and modifying each one to suit).

You could add test to each line.  This can be done in the Label expression:

```vbs
[field1] & " - Thinning" & vbcr & [field2] & " - Species" & vbcr & [field3] & " - Planting Year"
```

Which would output a label like:

```
T - Thinning
SS - Species
1970 - Planting Year
```

Comment: That is a workaround which could be useful if there's no specific way of annotating the labels as per the picture. The example picture of the annotated label which I used in the original question was taken off a map created using ArcMap, so I assumed there was a function for this. But I'm now wondering if the person who originally created it did so using another drawing program, and then inserted it into the map as an image.